# What is this Allen bolt on my novatech freehub, and what does it do?

Tags: maintenance, freehub

I've been servicing the novatech freehub on my Kona cyclo-cross bike after a particularly filthy ride. When removing the freehub I noticed this tiny Allen bolt by the inner pawls of the freehub. When I found it, it was partially unscrewed and loosely holding a small tube on the inside, however I don't know what it is! As far as I can tell this is the only function it does, as it does not affect the pawls engaging in the freehub.

Blue arrow is pointing towards it.

What is it, what does it do, and how tightly does it need to be done up?!

[image: Novatech freehub screw image]

Comment: Never worked with one of those, but it looks like a lock screw, to prevent rotation between that outer shell and the cylinder I see inside, on the left.

Comment: Maybe you can find its name in a diagram online. The name may reveal its purpose.

Comment: > *it was partially unscrewed and loosely holding a small tube on the inside,* Thus it looks like a [set screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_screw) for fastening that tube.

Answer (score 2):

I think it holds the spring in place and prevents it from rotating.
Found the spring as [Spare Part](http://www.nguide.eu/spare-parts/small-parts/4-pawls-spring). It would also makes sense as the ring has only one opening that is were the bolt is.

I would turn it so it sits flush with the freehub outer body so it can rotate without scratching the hub body.

Answer (score 1):

hello if i remember correctly that is the stop bolt for the needle bearing or spring pawls. if it had 0 tension on it i suggest lightly snugging it back it place.